# How I can paginate DB::select(...) result and get links() method?

Tags: laravel

I have a big and difficult SQL query. It works fine for me. And I have the following code in the controller:

```
 public function index(OpenRegDepDataReportInterface $openRegDepDataReport, Request $request): Renderable
    {
        $applications = $openRegDepDataReport->getReport($advertisers, $category);

        return view('applications.index', compact('applications'));
    }
```

So, the method `getReport` gives me a result of `DB::select('<here is my big diffecult SQL>')`, and, as well known it's an array.

But as you can see I'm trying to pass the result on a view. And, of course, I would like to call `$applications->links()` in the view, like for `eloquent` collection. Which is proper and faster way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination)

To display pagination at the table, you must call the select and then the pagination method.

in Controller:

```
$test = DB::table('users')->select('id')->paginate(10);
```

in View:

```
$test->links();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**, use `paginate()` method:

```
$basicQuery = DB::select(DB::raw("<here is the big diffcult SQL query>"));
```

However, `paginate()` works only on collections, and since you have an array of objects, you need to turn it into a collection first, using the [`forPage()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-forpage) method:

> The forPage method returns a new collection containing the items that would be present on a given page number. The method accepts the page number as its first argument and the number of items to show per page as its second argument:

```
$collection = collect($basicQuery);
$chunk = $collection->forPage(2, 3);
$chunk->all();
```

---

**Complicated answer**: build a paginator instance yourself:

```
$perPage = 10;
$page = $request->input("page", 1);
$skip = $page * $perPage;
if($take < 1) { $take = 1; }
if($skip < 0) { $skip = 0; }

$basicQuery = DB::select(DB::raw("<here is the big diffcult SQL query>"));

$totalCount = $basicQuery->count();
$results = $basicQuery
    ->take($perPage)
    ->skip($skip)
    ->get();

$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($results, $totalCount, $take, $page);

return $paginator;
```

I would recommend using the `paginate()` method.

You can read more about [Laravel's pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination).

Comment: Sorry, but the simple answer gives me `Call to a member function paginate() on array`

Comment: You have to convert your array into a collection. You can do it using Laravel's forpage() method https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-forpage I have updated the answer. You can also do it by just using collect() and then paginate().

Comment: `You can also do it by just using collect() and then paginate()` - does not work. Laravel tells me `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.` About `forPage`. Will I have `$applications->links()` method?

Answer (score 0):

So based on the documentation if your `$applications` returns a Query Builder result, then just append `->paginate(10);` to it.

> https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

```
$applications = $openRegDepDataReport->getReport($advertisers, $category)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work (( `getReport` returns result of the `DB::select(..)` and it's an array. It means I will have `call to undefined method paginate on array` error.